# Cambiar css mediante js vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentado cambiar las dimensiones de un `div` modificando el `css` del mismo mediante el modelo DOM de `JavaScript`.

```js
var mi_div = document.getElementById("prueba");
var get_width, get_height;
get_width = mi_div.offsetWidth;
get_height = mi_div.offsetHeight;

function mas_5_width(){
   mi_div.style.Width = get_width+5;
}

function menos_5_width(){
    mi_div.style.Width = get_width-5;
}

function mas_5_height(){
    mi_div.style.Heigth = get_height +5;
}

function menos_5_height(){
    mi_div.style.Heigth = get_height - 5;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:3px 5px;
    background-color: green;
}
.cabecera{
    border:solid black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    background-color: #20BE84;          
}

button{

    background-color: #E00B38;
    border: solid black;
}
button:hover{

    background-color: #FFCB18;
    border: solid black;

}
.prueba{
    border: solid;
    width: 170px;
    height: 180px;  

}
.prueba, .prueba p{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecera" >
    Cambiando dimension de los div
</div>

<div>
    <button onclick="return mas_5_width()">Width +5</button>
    <button>Width -5</button>
    <br>
    <button>Height +5</button>
    <button>Height -5</button>
</div>

<div class="prueba" id="prueba">
    Contenedor de prueba
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dos cosas importantes para que su código funcione.

- `Width` es incorrecto , las propiedades deben ir en minúsculas. `width`
- La propiedad no solo acepta valores numéricos si no también debe especificar el tipo de medida *(px,em,etc)*
- Además tener en cuenta que para modificar los valores en cada `click` ,debe obtener el ancho actual del elemento dentro de la función.
- Una consideración importante es que si desea disminuir el ancho del elemento debería especificar el tamaño del `border` es decir  `border: 1px solid ;` o el que desea si no podría tener problemas  o en su defecto añadir la propiedad [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)  *Una propiedad muy importante para cambiar el modelo de caja*

```js
var mi_div = document.getElementById("prueba");
function mas_5_width(){
  const get_width = mi_div.offsetWidth;
  mi_div.style.width  = get_width+5 +"px";
}

function menos_5_width(){
  const get_width = mi_div.offsetWidth;
  mi_div.style.width = get_width-5 +"px";
}
```

```css
.prueba{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 170px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="return mas_5_width()">Width +5</button>
<button onclick="menos_5_width()">Width -5</button>
<div class="prueba" id="prueba">
   Contenedor de prueba
</div>
```

Comment: estupendo, una ultima cosa, como es para restar, puede parecer obvio pero no me sale como yo pensaba. muchas gracias

Comment: @Selito95 ¿Qué es lo que no le "sale"? actualicé mi respuesta. si tiene problemas o dudas no dude en comentar.

Comment: mira, lo que no me sale es en vez de aumentar el widht y el height en +5, cuando lo intento para haer el -5 no me sale, puede parecer muy obvio pero no lo consigo

Comment: Mira asi lo tengo yo, que es igual y lo que hace es seguir aumentando pero menos que cuando le doy al +5, es muy extraño  -->

function menos_5_width(){
  var mi_div = document.getElementById("prueba");
  var get_width = mi_div.offsetWidth;
  mi_div.style.width = get_width-5 +"px";

 }

Comment: @Selito95 revisar mi ultimo punto en mi respuesta . Saludos , si tiene problemas no dude en comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Usando jquery es muy sencillo utilizando la funcion .Css()

```
$("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

y animandolo tambien con la funcion .animate()

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: no eres el primero que me lo dice, pero desgraciadamente tiene q ser vanilla JS de todas muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para usar el css desde javascript, se usa la propiedad "style" del objeto.
Por ejemplo:

```
prueba.style.width="100px";
prueba.style.height=variable+"px";    
prueba.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es que cuando presionen algun boton el tamaño del `div` aumente o se haga mas pequeño deberias hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent-buttons")
const test = document.getElementById("div-test")

function widthOrHeight(el, cuantoSumo) {
  const w = test.offsetWidth
  const h = test.offsetHeight
  
  const dataTest = el.dataset.test
  
  const qus = dataTest.slice(0, dataTest.indexOf(" "))
  const sumoOResto = dataTest.slice( dataTest.indexOf(" ")+1, dataTest.length)
  
  let wOh
  
  (qus == "width") ? wOh = w : wOh = h
  
  test.style[qus] = sumoOResto == "+" ? 
    wOh + cuantoSumo +"px" : wOh - cuantoSumo +"px"
}

parent.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const target = e.target
  
  if(target.hasAttribute("data-test")){
    widthOrHeight(target, 10)
  }
 
})
```

```css
#div-test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-buttons">
  <button data-test="width +">Width +5</button>
  <button data-test="width -">Width -5</button>
  <button data-test="height +">Height +5</button>
  <button data-test="height -">Height -5</button>
</div>

<div id="div-test"></div>
```